# QEMU-sparc can't open to file

Tags: c, fopen

I am pretty new about QEMU. I am working on QEMU emulation for SPARC microcontroller in my virtual machine which is Ubuntu 20.04.3. I would like to read data from .raw file but fopen functions doesn't work.

I am using eclipse for compiler.

Code Example :

```
FILE *fake;

if((fake = fopen("/home/rtems/Desktop/file.raw","r"))== NULL){
    printf("File doesn't created !\n");
}
```

File path is correct. There is no doubt.

I am always getting same error even if I can try to open file for write.

Do I need to change something for file access or do I need to convert my raw binary file to another format to access?

Comment: What is the reason for the error? What does `perror("fopen")` show?

Comment: perror("fopen") returns -> No such file or directory

Comment: There is some doubt, then. :)

Comment: make sure that the relative path is relative to your ".exe" file, not the ".c" file

Comment: @abdoSalm It's an absolute path.

Comment: Path is correct, I need to solve file access problem I suppose.

Comment: You would get a different error message if it were an access problem. "No such file or directory" means exactly what it says.

Comment: I am thinking that I am in emulator and I can't reach host machine(ubuntu virtual machine) files because my files are in host machine.